# WPF. Hide taskbar in kiosk mode application

Tags: c#, wpf, taskbar, kiosk-mode

I have a Windows 8.1 wpf application that can change its mode: kiosk or maintenance. For the kiosk mode I have a code:

`window.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
window.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
window.Topmost = true;`

It work very good, but when I change the mode from the maintenance to the kiosk mode I have a problem: if window was maximized before (window.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized) a taskbar stay visible.
I tried resolve this problem: I calculated monitor width and height using User32.dll:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.SourceInitialized += new EventHandler(win_SourceInitialized);
    }

    void win_SourceInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.IntPtr handle = (new WindowInteropHelper(this)).Handle;
        HwndSource.FromHwnd(handle).AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(WindowProc));
    }
    private static System.IntPtr WindowProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        switch (msg)
        {
            case 0x0024:
                WmGetMinMaxInfo(hwnd, lParam);
                handled = true;
                break;
        }
        return (IntPtr)0;
    }

    private static void WmGetMinMaxInfo(System.IntPtr hwnd, System.IntPtr lParam)
    {
        MINMAXINFO mmi = (MINMAXINFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MINMAXINFO));

        // Adjust the maximized size and position to fit the work area of the correct monitor
        int MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST = 0x00000002;
        System.IntPtr monitor = MonitorFromWindow(hwnd, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);

        if (monitor != System.IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            MONITORINFO monitorInfo = new MONITORINFO();
            GetMonitorInfo(monitor, monitorInfo);
            RECT rcMonitorArea = monitorInfo.rcMonitor;
            mmi.ptMaxPosition.x = rcMonitorArea.left;
            mmi.ptMaxPosition.y = rcMonitorArea.top;
            mmi.ptMaxSize.x = Math.Abs(rcMonitorArea.right - rcMonitorArea.left);
            mmi.ptMaxSize.y = Math.Abs(rcMonitorArea.bottom - rcMonitorArea.top);
        }
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(mmi, lParam, true);
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    internal static extern bool GetMonitorInfo(IntPtr hMonitor, MONITORINFO lpmi);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool GetCursorPos(ref Point lpPoint);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    internal static extern IntPtr MonitorFromWindow(IntPtr handle, int flags);
```

But it don't work after maximizes window in maitenance mode whatever. I understand that WindowState is WindowState.Maximized already and event of change window size do not happen. But I don't know how I can resolve it.
Of course, I can change the size of my window before maximizing:

```
window.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
window.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
window.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
window.Topmost = true;
```

It work, but I see flicker of the window. It's very bad for me.
I hope somebody had this bug and he resolved it happily.

Comment: try setting window.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize and see if it helps

Comment: Thank you. But I tried it too. It didn't help

Comment: You can also try setting MinHeight and MaxHeight insted of just Height property.